# Building a simple calculator and having problems with string formatting when returning the remainder

Tags: python, calculator

I'm building a basic calculator, and keep getting "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" at a line with returning the remainder. How can I fix this?

```
a = (input())
b = (input())
c = str(input())
if (b==0.0) and ((c=='mod') or (c=='/') or (c=='div')):
    print ('Zero division!')
if c == '+':
    print(a+b)
if c == '-':
    print(a-b)
if c == '/':
    print(a/b)
if c == 'mod':
    print(a % b) #this is the problem line
if c == 'pow':
    print(a**b)
if c == 'div':
    print(a//b)
```

Comment: I think input reads the value as a string so the other operations probably aren't doing what you expect. If you change the type to a float or int it should work. `float(input())`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `input()` returns a String typ you should change it to `float(input())` so that you can perform arithmetic operations with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your input for variable 'a' and 'b' doesn't have any typecasting for float or int, This should fix the problem:

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
c = str(input())
if (b==0.0) and ((c=='mod') or (c=='/') or (c=='div')):
    print ('Zero division!')
if c == '+':
    print(a+b)
if c == '-':
    print(a-b)
if c == '/':
    print(a/b)
if c == 'mod':
    print(a % b)
if c == 'pow':
    print(a**b)
if c == 'div':
    print(a//b)
```